# Duplicity restore with ftplicity fails because of different volume gpg key

Tags: debian, backup, duplicity

I'm trying restore my backup made on remote ftp server but i have problem because backup was made with different gpg key and then incremental backups was made with second gpg key. I get

```
/usr/local/bin/ftplicity backup restore /home
Start ftplicity v1.4.2.1, time is 05/05/15 10:41:35.
Using profile '/root/.ftplicity/backup'.
Using installed duplicity version 0.6.18, gpg 1.4.12 (Home: ~/.gnupg)
Test - Encryption with key 12345678 (OK)
Test - Decryption with key 12345678 (OK)
Test - Compare Original w/ Decryption (OK)
Cleanup - Delete '/tmp/ftplicity.25274.1430815295_*'(OK)

--- Start running command RESTORE (10:41:35.239) ---
Running duplicity - FAILED (code 22)
Output: NcFTP version is 3.2.5
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Tue Oct  1 20:42:41 2013
Volume was signed by key 87654321, not 12345678
--- Finished (10:41:52.348) - Runtime 00:00:17.108 ---
```

I have both gpg keys but using this: 12345678 key but before i was using 87654321 and now i cant restore backups.

Making backup going OK there is problem with restore or simple fetch file from backup because of

```
Volume was signed by key 87654321, not 12345678
```

let me know

Comment: are you sure that the restore didn't went through. the volume signature warning might lead to an error exit status, but not interrupt the restore.

Comment: yes im sure, no files was restored, i've check double times.